# How to add missing values in a table based on other table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table1 & Table2

Table1

```
[Category]
=====*=====
C&D   |
Market     |
Swift      |
Asit       |
other      |
------------
```

Table 2

```
[Client]  [Category] 
A     |  C&D
A     | Market
A     | Swift
A     | Other
B     | C&D
B     | market
B     | Other
C     | market
C     | Other
C     | Swift
C     | Asit
```

how to add the missing `Category` under `client` in table 2. For example 'swift' is missing in 'B' and 'C&D' is mising in C; how to add these items in B & C?

Note: I tried to put everything on table but i dont know how to make good table to be posted in stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest is probably to make a cross join of distinct clients on categories and save this result as your new complete table.

EDIT: changed code to work in Access. It ia actually a little different, sorry about that!

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table_2.Client, Table_1.Category INTO Table_3
FROM Table_1, Table_2;
```

Comment: Note that the question is about MS Access, not SQL Server.